# AWS EC2 suddenly cannot connect to RDS?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Suddenly, wordpress cannot connect to my RDS. all configurations and inbound/outbound rules are correct. I also tried creating basic php function to connect.. I tried it on my local machine and it's working but not on my EC2 server.

```
$mysqli_connection = new MySQLi('xxxx.xxxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com', 'db_user', 'db_pass', 'db_name');
if ($mysqli_connection->connect_error) {
   echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;
}
else {
   echo "Connected.";
}
```

Error: **php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known**

Just this morning this happened, I didn't do anything at all. Maybe this is an Apache error or something? any help please?

Comment: use your ec2 private ip into security group for incoming connection to allow connection from your ec2 to RDS.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit i already allowed all IP tho

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: that's what im trying to figure out. I tried 2 different AWS RDS btw, both cannot connect.

Comment: so it's `connection timeout` error right?

Comment: no, it's " php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202854/discussion-between-dhaval-purohit-and-acd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those who might be facing the same issue. Rebooting the EC2 instance fixed the problem.

Also, check if your volume is not full. run **df -a** in your ec2 through ssh to check